# В Python получаю ошибку reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

Tags: python, sympy, type-error

Столкнулся с ошибкой

> TypeError: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

В чем может быть проблема?

Код:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
from sympy import symbols, prod

x = symbols('x')
string_one = [0.3091,-0.0304,-0.0271,0.0054,0.0025,-0.0016,0.0019,-0.0046,0.0099,-0.019]
x_col_list = [0.0, 0.3142, 0.6283, 0.9425, 1.2566, 1.5708, 1.885, 2.1991, 2.5133]

 # идем по дельтам первой строки:
num=1
for delta in string_one:
    # идем по столбику иксов: 
    for args in x_col_list:
        polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 )  *prod(x - args)
        num+=1
    print(polynom)
```

Ошибка появляется в строке `polynom = round( ( delta/(factorial(num)*h**num) ), 4 )  *prod(x - args)`

Comment: "NameError: name 'h' is not defined"

Comment: Ошибка в этой части кода: `prod(x - args)` Вы что собственно пытаетесь тут вычислить? `x` - символ, в `args` - число, `prod` - вычисляет произведение элементов итерируемого объекта. Что тут итерировать - непонятно.

Comment: Ваш код может быть упрощён до `x = symbols('x'); prod(x)`. Что вы хотели сделать вычисляя произведение одной переменной?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, здесь именно нужна формула - вообще я пытаюсь получить полином Ньютона через интерполяцию. Таким образом, "x" мне нужен как символ - то есть на выходе ожидал=ю формулу полинома

Comment: @CrazyElf, речь о символах. Строю формулу полинома, поэтому применил модуль `sympy`